# Ext js : global this variable how to access in the button handler using bind?

Tags: extjs

I have a global variable this.myItems .
In ext js i have created a button and in its handler Im not able to access this.myItems. In handler this refers to button and how can i bind to gobal object? is there any way to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have a global variable `this.myItems`. `this` in JavaScript is never a global variable. `this` refers to the current instance of the object in the scope of which the code is executed.

Now to your problem. There are more than one way to achieve this.

- instead of using `handler`, which takes a function, you can use `listeners` which allows you to pass in the scope as a parameter.

  ```
  listeners: {
      click: {
          fn: function(button){}, 
          scope: //put here the variable you want to access with this 
      } 
  }
  ```
- use `addListener` which allows you also to specify a scope.
- define the handler function as a method of the controller. Instead of settings the handler in the view, set in in the controller's `init` method.

  ```
  init: function() { 
      this.control({ 
          'button': { click: this.onButtonClick} 
      }); 
  },
  onButtonClick: function(button) {
  ```

I prefer the third solution, because it allows for a clean separation between the view and the behavior. Also MVC is a good base to get maintainable code.